# Sql select max from result column

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I am trying to select the MAX from another query result which returns only one column with values.

The query which gives me the column with all the values from which I want to only select the max is:

```
SELECT perfy as perf
FROM aasv_chart5
UNION
SELECT perfcumu as perf
FROM aasv_chart5
```

This returns

```
PERF
-2.9
1.4
12.5
14
```

now I want to select the Max value from that. I tried something like..

```
select MAX(SELECT perfy as perf
    FROM aasv_chart5
    UNION
    SELECT perfcumu as perf
    FROM aasv_chart5) FROM aasv_chart5
```

Answer (score 3):

use your first query as a subquery, but use MAX on a field, not on the query

```
SELECT MAX(perf) from 
  (SELECT perfy as perf
   FROM aasv_chart5
   UNION
   SELECT perfcumu as perf
   FROM aasv_chart5) s
```

depending on your dbms, your could also do

```
select max(greatest(perfy, perdcumu))
from aasv_chart5
```

or if `greatest` in not there

```
select max(case when perfy > perdcumu then perfy else perdcumu end)
from aasv_chart5
```

**EDIT**

from your comment, you can do

```
select id, 
  (select max(greatest(perfy, perdcumu))
  from aasv_chart5) as maxVal
from aasv_chart5
```

or

```
select id, s.maxval
from aasv_chart5
cross join  (select max(greatest(perfy, perdcumu)) as maxval
  from aasv_chart5) s
```

Comment: Great! Much appreciated

Comment: Now how would I add select of another column (let's say the ID column). So I have 4 rows in my table and want the IDs (1,2,3,4) and also the MAX as second column (the MAX in every row)

Comment: @Silvanmidix what's your dbms, by the way ?

Comment: It's Oracle. I am querying with iReport and because the software (iReport) is not very smart I need to put the data together as nicely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT max(abc.perf)
FROM
(SELECT perfy as perf
    FROM aasv_chart5
    UNION
    SELECT perfcumu as perf
    FROM aasv_chart5) as abc
```